# Slow Collection Querying - Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a collection that contains a calendar of events for a year. For example holiday leave, sick leave etc.

I'm trying to build a calendar to display these but it run very slow so I think I must be doing it badly.

I'm looping through each day of the year by Carbon dayOfYear and I have the following getter which I call to pull out the events for that day:

```php
public function getDayOfYearAttribute()
{
    $starter = Carbon::parse($this->date);
    return $starter->dayOfYear;
}
```

I call it with:

```php
$today = $caldays->where('day_of_year', $dayofyear);
```

and then loop through any events to display.

What would be a better way to do this?

Thanks.

this is my controller:

```php
public function fullcalendar()
{
    $ret = \App\CalDay::all();
    $ret = $ret->sortBy('day_of_year');
    //++ default to this year
    $year = Carbon::now()->format('Y');
    return View::make('holidaycal.home')
    ->with('year', $year)
    ->with('caldays', $ret);
}
```

this is my code with the loop. its not in blade yet so bit of a mess, just testing the logic.

```php
$starter = Carbon::parse($year.'-01-01 00:00:00.000000');

echo '<table width="6325px" class="table table-striped table-bordered">';

$dayofyear=1;

for ($x = 1;$x < 13; $x++) {
    $starter->month = $x;

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td width="125px">';
    echo '</td>';
    for ($y = 1;$y < $starter->daysInMonth + 1; $y++) {
        echo '<td width="200px">';
        $starter->day = $y;
        echo $starter->isoFormat('ddd Do MMM');
        echo '</td>';
    }
    $starter->day = 1;
    echo '</tr>';

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo $starter->englishMonth;
    echo '</td>';

    for ($i = 0; $i < $starter->daysInMonth; $i++) {
        $today = $caldays->where('day_of_year', $dayofyear);

        echo '<td class="text-tiny">';
        foreach ($today as $event) {
            echo '<div>';
            echo $event->user->name .'('. $event->value .')<br/>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
        echo '</td>';

        $dayofyear++;
    }

    echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
```

table migration:

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('cal_days', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');

            $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->index();

            $table->dateTime('date');

            //+ days or hours
            $table->string('type','1')->default("D"); //D=days,H=hours

            $table->decimal('value',5,2)->unsigned()->index();
            $table->bigInteger('added_by_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->index();
            $table->integer('time_type_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->string('description',100)->nullable();

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide some more code (particularly the loop). It's hard to know what is actually happening here with what you've shown us. What is `$caldays` ?

Comment: How many items are returned from database? And what part is running slow specifically?

Comment: it runs fine up until this bit: $today = $caldays->where('day_of_year', $dayofyear). Its taking about 20 seconds to return 200 items but my final database will have upto 5000.

Comment: how big is your table? Maybe an index is in order.

Comment: The tables quite small. The dayOfYear property isnt in the table though, its a getter that gets dayOfYear from the date field. Im now wondering if that is causing the slowdown.

Comment: Does your model include `day_of_year` in `$appends`?

Comment: And what does your table look like? What is the `date` column? Is it listed in `$dates` on your model?

Comment: I'm not sure what $appends is sorry? yeah date is in the $dates in model. Ive added the table above.